# R: How to use a different column in your legend

Tags: r

Is it possible in R to use produce a chart using one column to segment the data, but put another column's text into the lengend and axes? Here's an example of what i mean:

### Create tibble

```
> device  = c("W000000", "W000002", "W000012")
> sum_18 = c(0.5, 0.6, 0.7)
> sum_16 = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.05)
> sum_12 = c(0,0,0)
> name = c("A", "B", "C")
> my_matrix = cbind(device, sum_12, sum_16, sum_18, name)
> my_matrix <- my_matrix %>% mutate(sum_16 = as.numeric(sum_16))
> my_matrix <- my_matrix %>% mutate(sum_18 = as.numeric(sum_18))
> my_matrix <- my_matrix %>% mutate(sum_12 = as.numeric(sum_12))
> my_matrix
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  device sum_12 sum_16 sum_18 name 
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>
1 W0000000   0.05    0.5 A    
2 W0000002   0.05    0.6 B    
3 W0000012   0.05    0.7 C
```

### Create Chart

```
threshold_colours <- usecol(pal = pal_seeblau, n = 3)

## Build Chart
who_threshold_chart <-
  who_threshold_data %>%
  # my_matrix %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  gather("sum_temp", "hours", -c(device_id)) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x = device_id, y = hours,
             fill = factor(sum_temp))) +
  
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width = 0.6, colour = "#e9ecef") +
  
  

  scale_y_percent(limits = c(0, 1.0)) +

  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 7, angle = 60, hjust = 1),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 7),

        legend.position = "bottom",
        legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  
  # scale_fill_discrete(name = "WHO Threshold", labels = c("below 12°C", "below 16°C", "below 18°C")) +

  # scale_fill_nord(palette = "lumina",
  #                 labels = c("below 12°C", "below 16°C", "below 18°C")) +
 guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Night-time temperature fell", title.position = "top"), drop = FALSE) +
 scale_fill_manual(values = threshold_colours, labels = c("below 12°C", "below 16°C", "below 18°C")) +

  xlab("") +
  ylab("of total night-time hours") +
  labs(fill = "")
```

[image]

Here's a chart with 3 devices. The x axis shows the device values. Is it possible to show the name. This code will run dynammically with any number of devices, so hard coding it in is not an option. And in this data set, the 'name' is more like a factor with only a small number of values. So, I can't just use name instead of device. The data would get all smooshed together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if `name` goes to both x-axis and label...

```
my_matrix %>%
  reshape2::melt() %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = device, y = value, fill = factor(variable))) +
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", width = 0.6, colour = "#e9ecef") +
  scale_y_percent(limits = c(0, 1.0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = my_matrix$name) +
  theme_ipsum() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 7, angle = 60, hjust = 1),
          axis.text.y = element_text(size = 7),
          
          legend.position = "bottom",
          legend.title = element_text(size = 10),
          legend.text = element_text(size = 10)) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Night-time temperature fell", title.position = "top"), drop = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("blue", "steelblue", "skyblue"), labels = name) +
  
  xlab("") +
  ylab("of total night-time hours") +
  labs(fill = "")
```

[image: label and axis]